# confusing syntax of cin.get()

Tags: c++, get, delimiter

I read a book which mentions that cin.get() will keep delimiter in the input stream, thus, the result of a following consecutive calling with the same delimiter is an empty line. So I wrote the following code to test this property and other.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char array[10];
  int character;
  cin.get(array, 10, 'a');
  cout << endl << array << endl;
  cout << cin.eof() << endl;
  cin.get(array, 10, 'a');
  cout << "not ignored: " << array << endl;

  cin.ignore();
  cin.get(array, 10,'a');
  cout << "ignored: " << array << endl;

  while((character=cin.get())!=EOF){}
  cout << character << endl;
  cout << cin.eof() << endl;
}
```

I then type in "Miami is a city(Enter)" in the terminal, get the following results:

```
Mi
0
not ignored: 
ignored: 
-1
0
```

I don't make sense several points. I didn't input ‘EOF’, but the character holds value of '-1'. I guess it might be that the second cin.get(array, 10, 'a'); get an empty line, it just views it as ‘EOF’? Am I right? If so, it makes sense that no other chars follows "ignored:". But if so, why the last statement print out '0'? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

> If no characters were extracted, calls `setstate(failbit)`. In any case, if `count>0`, a null character (`CharT()` is stored in the next successive location of the array.

Since, no characters were extracted in the second call

```
cin.get(array, 10, 'a');
```

`failbit` was set. You'll have to clear the state before you can read more characters from the string.

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char array[10];
  int character;
  cin.get(array, 10, 'a');
  cout << endl << array << endl;
  cout << cin.eof() << endl;

  cin.get(array, 10, 'a');
  // failbit is set since no characters were extracted in the
  // above call.

  cout << "not ignored: " << array << endl;

  // Clear the stream
  cin.clear();

  cin.ignore();
  cin.get(array, 10,'a');
  cout << "ignored: " << array << endl;

  while((character=cin.get())!=EOF){}
  cout << character << endl;
  cout << cin.eof() << endl;
}
```

Comment: But in the old code, with the failbit set, why character will get value of '-1' and cin.eof() returns '0'? Can you offer further explanation? Thanks! as indicated at the link you offer, 1) otherwise, sets eofbit. So, cin.eof() supposed to give 1?

Comment: @Neymar87, `cin.get()` will return EOF if `failbit` is set even when EOF has not been reached. `cin.eof()` returns `true` only when EOF has been reached. Hope that makes sense.